# Tools / best practices for managing composite application components?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mef, nuget, composition

We are building a composite application framework based on [ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and [Microsoft's new lightweight composition container](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Composition). Our team will deliver products based on this framework.  Customer IT shops will then have the freedom to swap out parts of the application for custom parts they would develop themselves. Along the way, the customers would take version upgrades from us as part of their support contracts.

The difficulty we are encountering is in the area of package and dependency management.  NuGet seems to be the defacto standard for this in the Microsoft world.  However, it seems focused on hard set references at design time.  In our scenario, we have very few design time dependencies as everything is interface based.  The concrete implementations are not known until run time and can be changed by the customer.

Are there tools or best practices for managing this type of environment?  Does anyone have recommendations based on their experience with scenarios like this?